# How to place content in proper table format in repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater like this

```
<ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="product">
                            <a href="#" class="info">
                                <table class="holder">
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="repContent" runat="server">
                                        <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>

                              <%# (Container.ItemIndex + 4) % 4 == 0 ? "<tr>" : string.Empty %>

                                 <td>
                                    <img src='<%#"/productimages/main/" + Eval("PhotoName").ToString().Trim()  %>' alt="No Image" />
                                    <span class="book-name"><%#Eval("ProductName") %></span>
                                    <span class="author">by <%#Eval("CompanyName") %></span>
                                    <span class="description"><%#Eval("Description") %></span>

                                  </td>

                                <%# (Container.ItemIndex + 4) % 4 == 3 ? "</tr>" : string.Empty %>

                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
                                         </asp:Repeater>
                                 </table>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" class="buy-btn">BUY NOW <span class="price"><span class="low">$</span>22<span class="high">00</span></span></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>                   
                </ul>
```

and it is appearing like this in browser
[image: the images are not in proper row and sequence] 
How can this content can be made to look properly set in proper rows and columns in repeater.

Please tell me what manipulation should i mad in my code please.

Comment: Maybe if you try to add `<td valign="top">`, can you give us the live version of this page ?

Comment: @NandniJain , why your `<table>` tab is outside of your repeater's `ItemTemplate` ?

Comment: If you want to do it properly then don't put a table in a list. This is not well formed html.

Comment: I have placed the table in header template of repeater but no change , infact now i am getting content in single column and no of rows

Comment: @NandniJain Live Version, one url that I can see the page

Comment: The HTML here is totally invalid. A `table` within an `anchor` within a `list item`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that this piece of HTML is totally invalid (ul -> li -> div -> **a** -> **table**), try to set the cell vertical alignment to top (`<td valign="top">`).

A good advice. Try to use CSS and rewrite this using just divs and make it valid.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="product">
            <a href="#" class="info">
                <table class="holder">
                    <asp:Repeater ID="repContent" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                              <%# (Container.ItemIndex + 4) % 4 == 0 ? "<tr>" : string.Empty %>
                                  <td valign="top">
                                      <img src='<%#"/productimages/main/" + Eval("PhotoName").ToString().Trim()  %>' alt="No Image" />
                                      <span class="book-name"><%#Eval("ProductName") %></span>
                                      <span class="author">by <%#Eval("CompanyName") %></span>
                                      <span class="description"><%#Eval("Description") %></span>
                                  </td>
                              <%# (Container.ItemIndex + 4) % 4 == 3 ? "</tr>" : string.Empty %>
                          </ItemTemplate>                      
                      </asp:Repeater>
                  </table>
              </a>
              <a href="#" class="buy-btn">BUY NOW <span class="price"><span class="low">$</span>22<span class="high">00</span></span></a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```